# kendo dialog window out of bounds at multiple uploads selected

Tags: browser, kendo-ui

I have an issue regarding a kendo dialog window including an upload.
When I upload multiple elements the list gets longer and longer and at some point gets bigger than my browserwindow and runs out of bounds at the bottom of the screen.
The insert button then is below the bottom bound of the browser but the browser doesn't allow me to scroll (firefox + chrome).

How can I limit my window to the browser screen and not exceed it?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Name("ImageBrowser")
    .Content( Html.Partial("ImageBrowserContent").ToString())        
    .MinWidth(400)
    .MinHeight(800)
    .MaxHeight(1000)
    .MaxWidth(800)
    .Modal(true)
    .Visible(false)
)

@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
.Name("imageUpload")
.Messages(mess => mess.Select("Upload"))
.Async(a => a
        .Save("Upload", "Image")
        .Remove("RemoveUpload", "Image")
        .AutoUpload(true)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided a dojo here for you which hopefully is what you are after. 
https://dojo.telerik.com/eqaZibIL

It uses the javascript version but you can just apply the function I have created to the dialog initial event. like so:

```
 @Html.Kendo().Dialog().Events(e => e.InitOpen("dialog_resize"))
```

(This is some code I have modified for handling kendoWindow's so could be optimized more I think)

```
  function dialog_resize() {

  //THIS GETS THE POPUP DIALOG 
  var popUpDialog = $('#dialog').data("kendoDialog");

  //THIS GETS THE CONTENT AREA FOR THE ENTIRE DIALOG
  var contentArea = $(".k-widget.k-window.k-dialog");

  //THIS GETS THE ACTUAL CONTENT AREA OF THE DIALOG IE.WHAT YOU WANT DISPLAYED
  var innerForm = $("#dialog");

  var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
  var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
  //CALCULATE THE WIDTH OF THE DIALOG AND SET IT TO 80% 
  //OF SCREEN REALESTATE TO STRECH OUT. 
  //NOT REQUIRED IF YOU ARE SETTING THE WIDTH MANUALLY. 
  contentArea.width(windowWidth * 0.8)


  //CENTER THE DIALOG ON THE SCREEN.  
  popUpDialog.center();

  //GET 97% OF THE AVAILABLE DIALOG CONTENT AREA TO SHOW Y-SCROLL BAR
  var fixedHeight = (contentArea.height() * 0.97);
  var fixedWidth = contentArea.width() * 0.965;


  //SET THE HEIGHT, WIDTH AND SCROLL BAR OF THE CONTENT AREA
  //SHOWING BLUE BORDER TO SHOW THE ITEM IS POSITIONING CORRECTLY IN DIALOG
  innerForm.height(fixedHeight).width(fixedWidth).css({
    maxHeight: fixedHeight + 'px !important',
    maxWidth: fixedWidth + 'px !important',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    border: '1px solid blue'

  });
}
```

Hopefully you can follow what is going off here. 
As long as you have set the `maxHeight` for the dialog on initialization all this seems to work correctly. I have applied a blue border to the content area just for demo purposes so you can see it in action.

Comment: lovely! Thank you very much. I will look into it tonight but good structure and comments, helps a lot.

Comment: Perfect, did what it should do, or let's say I could perfectly adapt it to my needs! Great help!